# Recommended testing tools to test MySQL performance?

Tags: 12.04, server, performance, mysql

What is the recommended tool(s) for testing the performance of MySQL 5.5 (innodb) under Ubuntu 12.04?

We have purchased a new multi-cpu multi-core server to replace our current MySQL dual-core server. However, the MySQL performance is worse than our current server! We know we need to tweak the innodb parameters but it would be helpful if there is a tool out there that would test and make recommendations.

Comment: https://tools.percona.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How To Benchmark Your System (CPU, File IO, MySQL) With sysbench](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820321/please-recommend-performance-testing-tool-for-mysql-under-ubuntu-debian

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at mysqltuner.pl  which can be found [here](http://mysqltuner.pl)

Answer (score -3):

I agree with Jan, mysqltuner.pl is a fine tool for the first tuning steps of your MySQL server.

But MySQL is part of a whole IT system. Raw performance is one thing, but what about real-life performance? (I work as an engineer at Neotys, the software vendor of NeoLoad, a load testing tool since 2005.)

To complete your test, I advise you to take a look at NeoLoad (free 30-day evaluation on www.neotys.com) to validate the performance, robustness, and scalability of your server in the context of your application. You can record and generate load from the front-end of your IT system, and measure the performance of your MySQL server when your application is actually used.

For MySQL, here are the counters that NeoLoad monitors : http://www.neotys.com/product/monitoring-mysql-web-load-testing.html.
Also, NeoLoad provides threshold values—derived from industry best practices—to raise relevant alerts.

Regards,

Hervé Servy, Neotys Performance Engineer

Comment: This is basically an advertisement for a commercial product, so I consider this to be spam.

Comment: @gertvdijk: This might be an advertisement but this does try to answer the question. It provides an alternative answer although it's a commercial product. Moreover the user isn't trying to hide this fact and he has explicitly mentioned his relation to the particular product. And he is not going to find each and every question and promote this affiliated product. Hence, I would not consider this as spam. Even [faq] used to mention that there is no problem if we mention about things we are affiliated with if we give an explicit disclosure (not able to find it right now). Am I mistaken somewhere?